# Error in converting datetime in factor format into date

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, format

i am a rookie using r to conduct some time series analysis.
Here the column "date" is factor format, and i used the as.Date() function and ymd() function and try to convert it into Date format(belike 2015-04-01), but the two functions give me wrong answers

my data$Date is like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHMuE.png)

and the wrong answer is like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEPRO.png)
i wonder why it is and can anyone give me some solutions?

a lot thx!!!

Comment: Try `as.Date(dt, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thx@jpsmith, it works using data$Date = as.character(data$Date)
data["newdate"] = as.Date(data$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

## assuming that your date dataframe is like this

df <- data.frame(Date = as.factor(c("01/01/2016 16:00:00","02/01/2022 16:00:00","05/01/2022 16:00:00", "21/12/2022 16:00:00","03/09/2021 16:00:00", "21/12/2017 16:00:00")))

 df$Date %>% 
   as.character() %>% 
   str_remove_all(" .*") %>% 
   as.POSIXct(format = "%d/%m/%Y") %>% 
   strftime() -> df$Date
```

### Output

```
> df
        Date
1 2016-01-01
2 2022-01-02
3 2022-01-05
4 2022-12-21
5 2021-09-03
6 2017-12-21
```

hope this helps